# Android Listview - Expand to fit whole screen to eliminate white space

Tags: java, android, listview

my problem is as follows:

I have a listview with four elements at the moment. For most screen sizes, this will not use up the entire screen and leaves ugly unused space beneath. I'd like to expand the listview so that each item is spaced evenly and leaves no white space, but have been unable to find a solution.

Below is a picture of what I am seeing:

[image: example]

The red arrow I put in to show that I want the empty space beneath filled in by spacing the items evenly.

The listview is very basic, nothing fancy going on. Here is some code from my xml files:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/categoryListView"/>
```

The items are populated from a database. I was hoping there would be a simple solution, but haven't been able to find one. Can anyone help me with a solution?

Comment: You shold divide the screen height by amount of items you want on screen.

Comment: Amount of items is dynamic, which may be an issue if there are more items (things could get crowded). However, this may work if I can set a minimum size for each item I think. I will give it a shot and come back with my result

Comment: please provide XML of your list row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "You shold divide the screen height by amount of items you want on screen."

@marcelo, you answered my question in a comment so I can not accept it as the correct answer, but by doing this I was able to solve my problem. Here's what I did:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
minHeight = displaymetrics.densityDpi/(listOfCategories.size()-1);
```

First, I got the screen's metric values (this includes screen height and width, but density was what I used here). I then set the value `minHeight` to the density divided by the number of list items minus 1, which filled the screen nicely (although it brought the last item right to the border - I needed to add a small bit of padding later).

I then did the following to space the list items evenly:

```
TextView labelView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
labelView.setMinimumHeight(minHeight);
```

Setting the minimum height guarantees that if there are few list items, they will have a certain height that has already been calculated to evenly space them.

I also added some logic to ensure that the minHeight is set to 0 for cases where there are more list items that would require scrolling. For example, if there were any more than 4 list items, they'd just be set to the standard height from the xml file and would not require the additional spacing, and minHeight is basically overlooked in this case.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" //if it is in a vertical linear layout,remove this comment, when using
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/categoryListView"/>
```

when you give layout weight of 1, the view expands to all possible space.

But this also largely depends on your item row xml.

Answer (score -1):

or you may also use :

```
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
```

in your xml file.